# MySQL service on xamps Runs and then stops after a few seconds

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I'm running MySQL service on Xampp and it shows me running status and after a few seconds, it Shows me the message: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

I’ve tried to find if any other apps are using the MySQL's port but there weren't any and also change the port to 3307 just to be sure and I still get the error: Error:
"MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums"

This is the content of the log file:

```
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 78568030; transaction id 59486
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2019-10-23 11:56:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191023 11:56:35
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall xampp software and try again.

Comment: if I uninstall xamp will I have access to the databases in PHP my admin that I don't have a backup of??